# How to write into layered depth attachment in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to implement shadow mapping into company's renderer, but I'm stuck upon writting depth results into depth attachment. I want to write into depth attachment normalized distance from light to fragment via `gl_FragDepth` output variable inside fragment shader, but render doc shows me that depth attachment is not updated by it at all. As depth attachment I'm using view for layered 2D image with 6 layers and `CubeCompatible` flag set, with `D32Sfloat` format and during subpass image has layout `DepthStencilAttachmentOptimal`. Each of cube face has its own view and is attached as depth attachment inside render pass rendering into it. Render pass has attachment description set up as:

```
format = shadowCubeMap.getDescription().format;
samples = vk::SampleCountFlagBits::e1;
loadOp = vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eLoad;
storeOp = vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eStore;
stencilLoadOp = vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eDontCare;
stencilStoreOp = vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eDontCare;
initialLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eDepthStencilAttachmentOptimal;
finalLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eDepthStencilAttachmentOptimal;
```

And of course when creating pipeline for rp's subpass 0 (during which is set that layout stays eDepthStencilAttachmentOptimal), I setting up `PipelineDepthStencilState` as:

```
depthTestEnable = VK_TRUE;
depthWriteEnable = VK_TRUE;
depthCompareOp = vk::CompareOp::eLessOrEqual;
```

I checked several time that I have recorded cmd buffer properly (that I'm binding into cmd buffer state proper resources).

Render doc shows me that there are some vertices forming triangle coming out from vertex shader that should be rasterized and processed by fragment shader where I should be able to compute depth and write it inside attachment via gl_FragDepth, but nothing is written inside it. Have anyone clue where the problem should lie?

Sorry guys that I can't show you whole code, firstly all Vulkan code is abstracted via wrapper methods and objects, secondly and most importantly the code is proprietary.

p.s: I don't know what any more info I should include, but ask me for more details, if you find something that should help solve this case.

Comment: If you're using layered rendering, how do you select which layer to send which primitives to? That's usually done with a geometry shader, so let's see it. Also, layered rendering requires layered viewport/depth range settings. So where are those?

Comment: I have hoped that I would define to which layer pipeline will render via image views. I have six render passes where different render pass has different cube face attached as depth attachment. The approach to render throught geometry shader into different layers, using `gl_Layer` during single rp I tryied at first, but it doesnt update depth attachments either. Viewport's depth range is set to 0 - 1 range and extent and offset are set to cover whole cube face.

Comment: "*I have six render passes where different render pass has different cube face attached as depth attachment.*" Then you're not doing "layered rendering", which specifically refers to picking specific layers for a primitive based on `gl_Layer`.

Comment: You're not getting anything written to the depth buffer. What about the color buffer? Is it possible that the triangles are getting culled (e.g. backface culling), or that they're outside the viewport? Do you have rendering to just a single non-layered/non-cubemap color+depth buffer working?

Comment: Color buffer was pretty much the same I have tryied it also, with image format `R32_SFLOAT`. Culling is disabled and non-layered/non-cubemap color+depth buffer is working perfectly, it's last render pass in my rendering routine which renders whole scene with textures and phong lighting. When I check rendering state via renderdoc, it shows me that some of the render passes are producing some vertices on the output and viewport is set up to match dimensions of one texture face with offset { 0,0 } so I hope that they're not getting out of viewport?